# Extract substring from a column, and add a new column using bash

Tags: bash, find, extract

Sorry if it is a repost.

My data (in a tab delimited text file):

```
Number  Description
1   YR=2020 Country=country_A ID=QWE
2   YR=2020 ID=ASD
3   YR=2019 Country=country_B ID=ZXC
4   Country=country_C ID=POI
```

I would like to extract the information from the `description` column using bash.

Desired output:

```
Number  YR  ID
1   2020    QWE
2   2020    ASD
3   2019    ZXC
4   -   POI
```

Comment: Is the `Description` field really so plain (no quoting, spaces, etc...)?

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN  { OFS="\t" }                                  # set output field delimiter as tab
FNR==1 { print "Number","YR", "ID"; next }           # print header, skip to next input line
       { yr=id="-"                                   # init variables for new line
         for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {                       # loop through space-delimited fields
             if ($i ~ /^YR=/) yr=substr($i,4)        # save everything after the "="
             if ($i ~ /^ID=/) id=substr($i,4)        # save everything after the "="
         }
         print $1,yr,id                              # print new line
       }
' input
```

**NOTE:** remove `# comments ...` to declutter code

This generates:

```
Number  YR      ID
1       2020    QWE
2       2020    ASD
3       2019    ZXC
4       -       POI
```